# React Serviceworker register

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I am trying to install a service worker in React app. But when i try to register it, it fails with:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed

My code is in App.js and the code inside of it is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')})}
}
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>PWA Go!</h1>
  </div>
);

}
}
```

Also, all of my files are in the src folder. The files are:

index.js

App.js

offline.html

sw.js

My service worker(sw.js) has this code inside it:

```
this.addEventListner(`install`, (e) => {
e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(`V1`)
    .then((ref) => {
        ref.add(`offline.html`)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Something went wrong here : ${err}`);
    })
);
});
```

But I still keep on getting the above mentioned error. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, please tell me. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Which browser (and its version) are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I've tried to register the same service worker with a different javascript file in different project(Non-React project) and it worked fine! But when i am using it with React it screws up!!

Comment: Might be to do with "addEventListner" and not "addEventListener" ?

Comment: Nope...Tried it right now....problem still exists!

Comment: That error means you're having exceptions in your service worker file `sw.js` so service worker can not evaluate the code. It can either be a syntax error or a runtime exception. You should double check the file to make sure that it is really valid.

Comment: i have changed the service worker to log a message when it installs....but now it shows an error `Uncaught TypeError: this.addEventListner is not a function`

Comment: should be `this.addEventListener` instead.

Comment: @Lewis Your answer worked! I am so sorry for the the trouble!! Post your answer below and i will right the answer! That way you will get the points!

Comment: Ok let me leave an answer so others can read it more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means you're having exceptions in your service worker file `sw.js` so service worker can not evaluate the related code. It can either be a syntax error or a runtime exception. In this case, `this.addEventListner` must be `this.addEventListener` instead.